# Filtering Entities with type Entity Reference?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

How do I query using the string value for an entity reference object?

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("entityName");
query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
query.Criteria.AddCondition("parentaccountid", ConditionOperator.Like, "14%");
```

"parentaccountid" here is basically of type entityreference.

```
EntityCollection results = crmService.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

When I try to get the results I receive the error unable to cast & it is expecting GUID.

I know that this might not be possible but still I may be wrong.
Is there any alternate way to query using string for entity reference object?

Additional Info:

There is an entity "Opportunity", it has several attributes with names name,orderamount,parentaccountid etc.

I'm calling service as below after applying filters:

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("opportunity");
query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
query.Criteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Like, "14%");
FilterExpression childFilter = query.Criteria.AddFilter(LogicalOperator.Or);
childFilter.AddCondition("tmeic_proposalnumber", ConditionOperator.Equal, "XXXXXX");
EntityCollection results = crmService.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

I'm assigning the results as below:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("CustomerName");
try
{
    foreach (Entity item in results.Entities)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["CustomerName"] = item.Contains("parentaccountid") ? item.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("parentaccountid").Name : string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}
```

I'm binding this data table to datagridview in windows forms app:

```
dgv.DataSource=dt;
```

Now, I want to search using the customer name.

But when I add the filter as below it throws error because it is expecting GUID.

```
query.Criteria.AddCondition("parentaccountid", ConditionOperator.Like, "14%");
```

I assigned *GetAttributeValue("parentaccountid").Name* for customer name. My search parameter is name only as I'm displaying name in the datagridview instead of GUIDs.

But in the QueryExpression it asks for GUIDs. How do I achieve this?

Can you provide any link where we query by adding filters with types EntityReferences & the result is binded from datagridview?

Comment: Can you explain in what scenario you need to filter on a part of a Guid key? Guids are meant to have no meaning by themselves and should have quite random values. Maybe your requirement can be met in another way?

Answer (score 3):

You need to filter on the `name` attribute of the associated `account` entity.

Join the `account` entity to the `opportunity` entity and apply a `ConditionExpression` to it like this:

```
var query = new QueryExpression("opportunity");
LinkEntity link = query.AddLink("account", "parentaccountid", "accountid");
link.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.BeginsWith, "14");
```

Comment: This doesn't work as required because attribute accountid is in both account entity & opportunity entity.  opportunity has attributes accountid  & parentaccountid.

Answer (score 2):

While it appears that we're out of luck on getting the "like" operator to compare a string to a GUID on the fly, there are at least a couple potential workarounds:

1. Retrieve all the GUID's, convert them to a list of strings, and find your subset by querying that list (i.e. with LINQ).
2. Write a very simple onCreate plugin or workflow that sets a new text field on the entity to the GUID. Then you have the GUID as a string, to work with as you please.

Here's code I use in a workflow that does exactly what I'm describing (i.e. populates the GUID into a text field). It sets an output parameter to the GUID, then the next step of the workflow populates that value into the field.

```
public partial class GetGuid : BaseWorkflow
{
    [Output("Entity Id")]
    public OutArgument<string> EntityId { get; set; }

    protected override void ExecuteInternal(LocalWorkflowContext context)
    {
        EntityId.Set(context.CodeActivityContext, context.WorkflowContext.PrimaryEntityId.ToString());
    }
}
```

Please also note that while the "like" operator doesn't work for GUID's, "greater than" and "less than" do, so something like this works:

```
<fetch>
    <entity name="account" >
        <attribute name="accountid" />
        <attribute name="name" />
        <filter type="and" >
            <condition attribute="accountid" operator="gt" value="14000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
        </filter>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but there is a little mis-understanding. Actually, I meant a different question. I've added extra details to the question.

Answer (score 2):

**parentaccountid** is a  [Lookup Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607980.aspx#Anchor_1) .

LinkEnitity can only be applied for another entities.

The easy way for filtering is adding name at the end of attribute.

```
query.Criteria.AddCondition("parentaccountidname", ConditionOperator.Like, "%In%");
```

Thanks to Dave, refer here for [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230749/querying-lookup-with-name-in-dynamics-crm/45232436#45232436)