# Querying Lookup Property Attribute with "Name" in Opportunity Entity - Dynamics CRM Online

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I'm retrieving the results after connecting to the dynamics CRM as below:

```
CrmServiceClient crmConn = new CrmServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ConnectionString);
IOrganizationService crmService = crmConn.OrganizationServiceProxy;

QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("opportunity");    
query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
query.Criteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Like, "14%");

EntityCollection results = crmService.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

Now as the name is of type string, I was able to add condition & perform operations & get the results.

My requirement is I've to add another filter which is a lookup property "parentaccountid".

I'm trying to add the condition as below but it **throws cast exception error as it is expecting only GUID.**

```
query.Criteria.AddCondition("parentaccountid", ConditionOperator.Like, "%In%");
```

*Note: the type of parentaccountid is Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference when I retrieved from early results*

The reason is we can apply filter for parentaccountid only with GUID.

***Is there any way to add the condition based on "Name" instead of "Id"?***

Comment: I tried with the LinkEntities but I failed to achieve the required functionality. However, @Dave Clark has provided an exact answer I was looking for. Thanks Dave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just add `"name"` to the end of `"parentaccountid"`:

```cs
query.Criteria.AddCondition("parentaccountidname", ConditionOperator.Like, "%In%");
```

You'll notice that if you create an Advanced Find like this:

[image]

And then download the FetchXML, CRM just appends `"name"` to the end of lookup attribute name:

```xml
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="opportunity">
    <attribute name="name" />       
    <order attribute="name" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="parentaccountidname" operator="like" value="%In%" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

An alternative solution would be to use a `LinkEntity`, and query the name of the linked account.

Comment: thanks Dave this worked. But I tried query using the LinkEntity but I wasn't able to find the entity for this attribute "parentaccountid". So, I couldn't join with the opprtunity entity. Basically, parentaccountid is a lookup field. How can I use LinkEntity on lookup fields? Can you extend your answer with that?

Comment: Hi @ashveli, glad I could help. I think to answer your extended question, you'd need to ask a new question (as per SO's guidelines). Having said that there are many blog posts and even official Microsoft posts on [LinkEntity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.query.linkentity.aspx)

Comment: Well I searched through many articles but I couldn't find how to query linkentity with lookup property. All I could find was querying linkentity with entities like I was able to query opportunity &account. But, opportunity & parentaccountid I had no luck until you provided a way. Thanks again for that. I think it is not possible to query using linkentity and lookup property